# Adding CRS definition/details to layout in print composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I'm new to QGIS and I'm wondering if there's any way I can add a label to my map in composer with a similar format shown in the image below. I know that I can add the CRS and CRS definition using the layer property format but I would like a similar output to the one in the image.

The attached image is generated from Arc by the way.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Some of the informations you seek are **project-related** some are **map-related** (if i'm right...). You can retrieve most of them using integrated variables that already exist in QGIS.

When filling your label go to "**insert an expression**" then browse the categories "Variables" and/or "Layout"

For example (in "variables") :

```
project_crs, project_distance_units, project_ellipsoid
```

For the map scale u can use :

```
map_get(item_variables('your_map_name'), 'map_scale')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the projection string definition with `regexp_substr` (greedy so may not fit) or a dedicated Python function in Expressions. Then reuse this informations extraction from layer CRS to display what you want in the map composer.

Personnaly, I would clearly use Python functions for this intent. In the future, to avoid parsing, we may be able to use [PROJJSON](https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/blob/master/docs/source/specifications/projjson.rst), a JSON representation of projections and their parameters to simplify (PS: only available if using proj 6.2 or more)